# coredata override set value for relationship

Tags: core-data

I have a working  model in coredata with two entity:
- Customer
- Invoices

Customer has "invoices" property (1 to many) and  Invoices has "customer" property (1 to 1).
Everything worked until i override the "setCustomer" method on Invoice class.
I write this code

```
-(void)setCustomer:(Customer *)customer {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Customer"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:customer forKey:@"Customer"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Customer"];
    [self recalulatePriceAndDiscounts];
}
```

where "recalculatePriceAndDiscount" is my own method that i need to call when i select different customer.

When i use this code the inverse relationship (customer->invoices) isn't immediately available, i need to close and reopen my application to see customer's invoices.

There is some other method that i need to call?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom setter methods in Core-Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971806/custom-setter-methods-in-core-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property is called "customer" (with a lower-case "c") then you have to use that as key, e.g.

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"customer"];
// ... etc.
```